# Help identifying connector type on Nissan TV Tuner

Tags: connector

Can anyone identify the grey (24 pin) and white (6 pin) connectors on the Nissan TV Tuner pictured below.

[image: Nissan TV Tuner]

Don't currently have a pair of calipers. I have measured as best I can with a ruler.
The 20 pin grey connector is 35mm x 14mm
The 8 pin white connector is 15mm x 14mm

The workshop manual suggests connector type is TK but that's not entirely helpful without a manufacturer.

Mating half below, in case that helps.

[image: Mating Connector]

Comment: the manufacturer probably can ... is that all you want to know?

Comment: There are a few extra rules for component identification questions.  You should click "Tour" under "Electrical Engineering" at the bottom left of the page and read the rules so you can adjust your question.  In particular for connectors, Dimensions, pin pitch (center to center distance of pins from each other), pin dimensions.  Your picture appears to be adequate, but you need to measure and add that information.  A digital caliper helps a lot with the measurements if you can obtain one.